# Prove that $s$ is monotonic

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$s_n = \frac{n^2}{n^3 +1}$$

So Based on the searches I ave done so far I am led to believe that induction would be the general type of proof for a problem such as this.

$(Proof)$
Assume that $s_n >s_{n+1}.$ We want to prove that $\forall n \in N, |s_n-s_{n+1}|>0$

$(1)$For $n=1,  s_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ and $s_2 = \frac{4}{9}$, so $\frac {1}{2} > \frac {4}{9}. $

$(2)$ For $n=k, s_k = \frac {k^2}{k^3+1}$ and $s_{k+1} = \frac {(k+1)^2}{(k+1)^3 +1}$, so with some algebra that I am excluding for time sake we can conclude this

$k^4 + 2k^3 +k^2 -2k-1 > 0,$ which we can write as $k^2 + 2k + 1 > \frac{2}{k} + \frac {1}{k^2}, k \to \infty, (k^2 + 2k + 1)\to \infty$ and  $ \frac{2}{k} + \frac {1}{k^2} \to 0 $ , so $\frac {k^2}{k^3+1}> \frac {(k+1)^2}{(k+1)^3 +1}.$

$(3)$ For $n=k+1, s_{k+1} = \frac {(k+1)^2}{(k+1)^3 +1}$ and $s_{k+2} = \frac {(k+2)^2}{(k+2)^3 +1},$ so $\frac {(k+1)^2}{(k+1)^3 +1} > \frac {(k+2)^2}{(k+2)^3 +1},$ again with some algebra that I am excluding for time sake we can conclude this

$$k^4 +6k^3+13k^2+10k+1 >0$$

$$ k \to \infty, (k^4 +6k^3+13k^2+10k+1 ) \to \infty$$

Therefore by induction we can conclude that it is decreasing.

This is as far as I thought I had to take it, please let me know if there is more work or incorrect work. I don't think I have to prove if it is convergent or bounded in order to prove it is monotonic. Also did I need to do step $(3)$ to make my conclusion from induction or would steps $(1)$ and $(2)$ been sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

You're complicating things.

**Hint**:
$$\frac{n^2}{n^3+1} = \frac{1}{n+ \frac{1}{n^2}}$$

This simply shows that the increase of $n$ determines an increase in the denominator. Since the numerator is constant, one might simply assess our sequence is decreasing.

Comment: So I guess the main question I am trying to get to is this, regardless of which answer I choose (probably yours) i can conclude that this sequence is Monotone simply because it is decreasing?

Comment: Simply because it is decreasing? What is your definition of a monotonic function?

Comment: Say a sequence $s_n$ is increasing if $s_{n+1}$ is greater than, less than, less than equal to, or greater than equal to $s_n$ any of these are monotonic

Comment: So, if a sequence is strictly decreasing, how would you relate that with the concept of monotonicity ?

Comment: Basically is the condition is met for $s_n ( \lt \gt \le \ge )s_{n+1}, \forall n$ , than the sequence is monotonic

Comment: idk that is the definition my professor and the book we are using gives

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^3+1}$$

Now differentiate this function in respect of $x$.

$$f'(x)=\frac{2x(x^3+1)-x^2(3x^2)}{(x^3+1)^2}=\frac{2x-x^4}{(x^3+1)^2}=\frac{x(2-x^3)}{(x^3+1)^2}$$

For $x>\sqrt[3]{2}$ you can see that $2-x^3<0$, $x$ is positive and $(x^3+1)^2>0$. Hence, the derivative is strictly negative.

As this is true for all $x>\sqrt[3]{2}$ it is also true for all $n>1$. From this you can conclude, that s is also strictly monotonic.